# What is the fastest way to create 30_000 Widget objects?

Tags: jupyter, ipywidgets

I need to initialize a list of 30'000 Widget objects.
The below benchmarking shows that it takes 42 seconds.
Is there a faster way to do this?

```
from ipywidgets import Widget
import timeit
my_rep = lambda n: [Widget() for i in range(n)]

n_rep = 1_000 # 1.34 seconds
# n_rep = 5_000 # 6.88 seconds
# n_rep = 30_000 # 42 seconds

timeit.timeit(lambda: my_rep(n_rep), number=1) # increase "number=1" for more accurate estimate
```

Comment: List comprehensions, being Pythonic, are usually among the fastest ways to do things. Even faster is to do it lazily, using a generator; the initial creation is near instantaneous and you only pay for the Widget creation when you actually need it, instead of up front. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Trying to create a graph of nodes and edges with ipycytoscape. Issue [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/ipycytoscape/issues/275). Generator won't work

Comment: That seems like it might be an upstream architecture issue; again lazy loading would probably greatly improve runtime (eg only render/construct edges when they're in view, and unrender when they're not)

Comment: Well, it is what it is, and I'm trying to figure out a way around it

Comment: What kind of operations/searches are you trying to do with this graph? Maybe there are other packages out there with a more focused/performant setup?

Comment: I suspect that the performance hit happens here, where it unilaterally opens a comm interface on construction: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/8.0.0a6/ipywidgets/widgets/widget.py#L396

Comment: Here's how you _could_ instantiate the connection when needed, as seen in PRAW: https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/fdc8a29c977c95ff46a4107f902064d0b4d376c3/praw/models/reddit/base.py#L33

Comment: Good catch. I'll try it out